# Bootstrap Collapse Tree View with Tree Levels (using CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good day everyone, i have here a Tree View using Bootstrap Collapse.

I am trying to add the Collapse Level using CSS Counters, but unfortunately i'm having some glitches on the counters before each Collapse.

This is what i want to achieve

[image]

And this is what i got

[image]

Below is a sample code on what i'm currently working at.

Where am i going wrong? I merely don't have any idea why the CSS Counters are messing. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```css
.accordion.parent {
  counter-reset: level;
}

.accordion.parent .card:first-of-type {
  counter-increment: level;
}

.accordion.parent .card .card-header h5 button:before {
  content: counter(level);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion parent" id="accord1">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="head1">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col1">
     
    </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="col1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="head1" data-parent="#accord1">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="accordion" id="accord1_1">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="head1_1">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1_1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col1_1">
         
        </button>
              </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="col1_1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="head1_1" data-parent="#accord1_1">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="accordion" id="accord_2">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="head2">
                      <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col2">
             
            </button>
                      </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div id="col2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="head2" data-parent="#accord_2">
                      <div class="card-body">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="head1_2">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1_2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col1_2">
         
        </button>
              </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="col1_2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="head1_2" data-parent="#accord1_1">
              <div class="card-body">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

The following tree pattern needs the `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` assigned to an ancestor element that all `counter()` of the particular level.

> ```
> 1_______1 = #acc1 { counter-reset: A 0; counter-increment: A; }
>     |
>     2     = #acc2 { counter-reset: B 1; counter-increment: B; }
>  3__|__3  = #acc3 { counter-reset: C 2; counter-increment: C; }
>  |
>  4        = #acc4 { counter-reset: D 3; counter-increment: D; }
> ```
>
> <sup>**Note:** the default value of `counter-reset` is `0` and explicitly assigning it is optional. It is assigned in the example to show the increment pattern.</sup>

The rule set for the `counter()` on each level uses the [child combinator: `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Combinators_and_selector_lists) because without it the last rule set will override the previous ones because each level is nested within the other. The following pattern will isolate each level:

> ```
> #accN > .card > .card-header > h5 > button:before { content: counter(...); }
> ```

---

### [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

The HTML layout and some of the BS classes were either missing or assigned in the wrong order. Bootstrap examples in the documentation uses a ton of `<div>`s which makes nesting elements several levels deep very difficult. The following demo uses `<section>` and `<article>` to break up the monotony. Also, proper placement of BS classes are implemented in the demo as well (see sections on [card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/) and [accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example) components).

---

### Demo

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll
}

#acc1 {
  counter-reset: A;
  counter-increment: A;
}

#acc1>.card>.card-header>h5>button:before {
  content: counter(A);
}

#acc2 {
  counter-reset: B 1;
  counter-increment: B;
}

#acc2>.card>.card-header>h5>button:before {
  content: counter(B);
}

#acc3 {
  counter-reset: C 2;
  counter-increment: C;
}

#acc3>.card>.card-header>h5>button:before {
  content: counter(C);
}

#acc4 {
  counter-reset: D 3;
  counter-increment: D;
}

#acc4>.card>.card-header>h5>button:before {
  content: counter(D);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12'>
      <section id="acc1" class="accordion">
        <article class="card">
          <header id='hdr1a' class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1a" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col1a"></button></h5>
          </header>

          <section id="col1a" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="hdr1a" data-parent="#acc1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class='card-text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
              <p class='card-text'>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <footer class='card-footer'>
              <section id="acc2" class="accordion">
                <article class="card">
                  <header id='hdr2' class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col2"></button></h5>
                  </header>

                  <section id="col2" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="hdr2" data-parent="#acc2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class='card-text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                      <p class='card-text'>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </div>
                    <footer class='card-footer'>
                      <section id="acc3" class="accordion">
                        <article class="card">
                          <header id='hdr3a' class="card-header">
                            <h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col3a" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col3a"></button></h5>
                          </header>

                          <section id="col3a" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="hdr3a" data-parent="#acc3">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <p class='card-text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                              <p class='card-text'>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                            </div>
                            <footer class='card-footer'>
                              <section id="acc4" class="accordion">
                                <article class="card">
                                  <header id='hdr4' class="card-header">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col4" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col4"></button></h5>
                                  </header>

                                  <section id="col4" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="hdr4" data-parent="#acc4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                      <p class='card-text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                      <p class='card-text'>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <footer class='card-footer'></footer>
                                  </section>
                                </article>
                              </section>
                            </footer>
                          </section>
                        </article>
                        <article class="card">
                          <header id='hdr3b' class="card-header">
                            <h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col3b" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col3b"></button></h5>
                          </header>

                          <section id="col3b" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="hdr3b" data-parent="#acc3">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <p class='card-text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                              <p class='card-text'>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                            </div>
                            <footer class='card-footer'></footer>
                          </section>
                        </article>
                      </section>
                    </footer>
                  </section>
                </article>
              </section>
            </footer>
          </section>
        </article>

        <article class="card">
          <header id='hdr1b' class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-block btn-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1b" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col1b"></button></h5>
          </header>

          <section id="col1b" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="hdr1b" data-parent="#acc1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class='card-text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
              <p class='card-text'>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <footer class='card-footer'></footer>
          </section>
        </article>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer @zer00ne. Will experiment more on this and adapt on my current code. Have a great day! :)

Comment: That's awesome @TheTerribleChild . Happy coding!